# Magento 2. Adjust order of loading javascripts

Tags: magento2, javascript

I have the following navigation menu, loaded through Javascript like this:

```
<ul data-mage-init='{"menu":{"responsive":true, "expanded":true, "position":{"my":"left top","at":"left bottom"}}}'>
```

Is there a way to make this widget menu to load, in the footer, first than any other javascript? I heard it is possible by using j-query, but not sure how to achieve this.

Thanks for your collaborations